# I'm running into an infinite loop when searching for leaf nodes in a BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm having some trouble figuring out an issue in my code. I needed to do a search to find leaf nodes in a binary tree. When I run the debugger, and select this specific function to call (after creating the tree), I run into an infinite loop. Here is the code I wrote:

```
void BT::countleaves(node* p)
{
int count = 0;

if (isEmpty())
{
    cout << "   Tree is empty." << endl;
    return;
}

while (p >= NULL)
{
    inorderTrav(p->left);
    inorderTrav(p->right);

    if (p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        inorderTrav(p->left);
        inorderTrav(p->right);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at the values in the pointers.  Does A->B->A when traversing?  If so, input data issue.  Also would result in stack explosion if ran long enough.

Comment: You're traversing each child twice. You're also assuming that you always have both children. Also, what are `node`, `isEmpty`, and `inorderTrav`?

Comment: Just realized that - calling both left and right twice or more times.

Comment: `while (p >= NULL)` is unusual. What do you mean here?

Comment: p will always be `>=null`

Comment: @mad.meesh that brings up an interesting side question. Relational operators on pointers are only defined by the standard if the pointers are both in the bounds of the same object. `p` and `NULL` are not in the same object, so according to [expr.rel] the behaviour should be unspecified. I can't think of a good reason why an implementation wouldn't wind up returning true, but they could.

Answer (score 0):

Why `while(p >= NULL)` not `if(p !=null)` ?

```
 else
    {
        inorderTrav(p->left);
        inorderTrav(p->right);
    }
```

Well what for going to both left and right since one of the is null anyhow?